# Yacc error request for member "Token" in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I tried everything and I kept getting the following errors:

(line)20:31: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union

(line)22:38: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union

(line)27:108: error: request for member ‘val’ in something not a structure or union

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%option noyywrap
%option yylineno

%%
0|[1-9][0-9]* {yylval.val=atoi(yytext); return NUM;}
\*|\+         {yylval.val=yytext[0]=='+'?0:1; return OP;}
\(|\)          return yytext[0];
[ \t\n]       ;
.             yyerror("caracter invalido");

%%
```

And the yacc:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
extern int yylineno;
%}

%union {struct nodo{int val; struct nodo *next} *p; int val;}
%start lexp
%token<val> OP NUM
%type<p> larg arg
%type<val> exp

%%

lexp    : lexp exp 
    |   
    ;
exp : '(' OP larg ')' {struct nodo *p=$3->next;int val=$3->val;
              while(p){
                val=$2.val?(val+p->val):(val*p->val);
                p=p->next;}
              printf("R:%d\n", val); $$.val=val;}
    ;
larg    : arg larg {$$=$1; $1->next=$2;}
    | arg arg  {$$=$1; $1->next=$2;}
    ;
arg : NUM {$$= (struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo)); $$->next=0; $$->val=$1.val;}
    | exp {$$= (struct nodo *) malloc(sizeof(struct nodo)); $$->next=0; $$->val=$1.val;}
    ;
%%
int yyerror(char *s){fprintf(stderr, "linha %d: %s\n", yylineno,s); return 0;}
int main(){
yyparse();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try removing the `.val` from things like `$2.val`? Because of your `%token` and `%type` lines and the `<tag>` construct, the particular field of the union is already determined. In other words, you're doing things like `(yylval.val).val` in the generated C code.

Comment: Thank you it does make sense now after your explanation :D